# question regarding the geometric meaning of eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Ok so I've known how to get eigenvalues and eigenvectors for a while, but am becoming more interested in a 'simple' explanation of what actually is going on. I've looked up things on Google etc. What's confusing me is that it says x is an eigenvector of A if the image of x which is $\lambda x$ is parallel to x. Fine, but then even on wikipedia it shows a small graph where $Ax$ is lying along the vector x but it is just longer or stretched by $\lambda$. This obviously isn't parallel to x ? But x is an eigenvector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel in terms of linear algebra means that the two vectors have the same direction.  This can be characterised in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the cross product of the two vectors being zero.  This is equivalent to the two vectors having the same direction, as 
$$||a \times b|| = ||a|| ||b||\sin \vartheta \text{,}$$
where $\vartheta$ is the angle between the two vectors (note that this definition of parallel also implies that the zero vector is parallel to all vectors).

Also note that vectors can be picked up and moved around, so two vectors lying on top of eachother, as in your example, can be made parallel in the traditional sense by simply picking one up and moving it a bit to the side.

Another way to think geometrically of eigenvectors, which makes sense in all dimensions, not just 2 or 3, is that they are *scaled* by the linear operator (the matrix $A$) by the value $\lambda$ (the eigenvalue).  So eigenvectors are those that have only their magnitude changed by $A$, and not their direction.

Comment: Thank you so very much, that helps so much

Comment: I updated the answer - I meant to talk about cross products, not dot products (what I wrote before was, ummm, totally wrong).  Probably the best way to think about eigenvectors geometrically though is to think of them as being scaled without the direction changing, and "parallel" as meaning having the same direction.